# How do I use xUnit Assert.RaisesAny?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

How do I use xUnit Assert.RaisesAny()? I can't seem to find any examples.

I received the following syntax error

> The event 'IMqttServer.Started' can only appear on the left hand side
>   of += or -=

This makes sense since I am not subscribing to it but I don't know what syntax to use with RaisesAny()

Basically, I am just trying to check that the Broker started, an at least 1 client connected to it and that it stopped.

P.S. MqttServer is an Mqtt Broker implementation that is part of [MqttNet](https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet)

here is my Test

```
public class ResearchTestingOnly
{

    private readonly ITestOutputHelper output;

    public ResearchTestingOnly(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        this.output = output;
    }


    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {

        IMqttServer _mqttBroker = new MqttFactory().CreateMqttServer();

        var receivedEvents = new List<string>();

        _mqttBroker.ClientConnected += delegate (object sender, MqttClientConnectedEventArgs args)
        {
            receivedEvents.Add(args.ClientId);
        };

        Assert.RaisesAny<EventHandler>(_mqttBroker.Started);

        Assert.RaisesAny<MqttClientConnectedEventArgs>(_mqttBroker.ClientConnected);

        Assert.RaisesAny<EventHandler>(_mqttBroker.Stopped);

        //** Start Broker
        Task _brokerTask = Task.Run(() => _mqttBroker.StartAsync(new MqttServerOptions()));

        //** Wait 10 Seconds
        var pause = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        pause.WaitOne(10000);

        //** Stop Broker
        Task _brokerStopTask = Task.Run(() => _mqttBroker.StopAsync());

        //** Wait for Broker Tasks to Complete
        Task.WaitAll(_brokerTask, _brokerStopTask);

        output.WriteLine($"Number of Clients Connected: {receivedEvents.Count}");
        foreach(var b in receivedEvents)
        {
            output.WriteLine(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: examples from source repo https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/test/test.xunit.assert/Asserts/EventAssertsTests.cs#L58

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [the source for EventAssertsTests](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/test/test.xunit.assert/Asserts/EventAssertsTests.cs) (replaced `x` with `_mqttBroker`):

```
[Fact]
public static void GotExpectedEvent()
{
    var evt = Assert.RaisesAnyAsync<EventArgs>(
        h => _mqttBroker.Started += h,
        h => _mqttBroker.Started -= h,
        () => Task.Run(() => _mqttBroker.StartAsync(new MqttServerOptions())));

    Assert.NotNull(evt);
    Assert.Equal(_mqttBroker, evt.Sender);
    Assert.Equal(EventArgs.Empty, evt.Arguments);
}
```

Comment: Would have been even better if you adapted it to the OPs problem. :)

Comment: Yes, as Nkosi says, this helps but it is not a complete answer

Comment: I replaced 'x' with '_mqttBroker' for you. Hope it helps